# No TTable Component in Delphi XE8

Tags: database, delphi, ado, delphi-xe8

I think the title speaks for itself, I can’t find a TTable component in Delphi XE8. The functions `SetKey` and `GotoNearest` are not part of ADO, therefore the following code with a TADOTable does not work:

```
with tblCandidates do
begin
  SetKey
  FieldByName('Surname').AsString := edtSearch.Text;
  GotoNearest;
end;
```

Comment: Do you have BDE and DBTables in your uses?

Comment: When I add them to my uses I get the error “Cannot resolve unit name” @MorganThrapp

Comment: I just want to check:  What datatype is tblCandidates declared as, and what kind of database server or files are you using?  Btw, TAdoTable has its own Locate and Seek methods - see the OLH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My assumption is that you are asking how to find the BDE `TTable` component. Well, there is no such thing any more. From the [XE7 What's New](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#BDE_Removed):

> **BDE Removed**
>
> BDE, our oldest database solution, has reached the final stage of
>   deprecation, and has been removed from RAD Studio. This includes the
>   Bde.DBBdeWeb and Bde.DBTables units. Instead, use newer database
>   technologies such as FireDAC. For migration, see Migrating BDE
>   Applications to FireDAC.
>
> If you need to continue using BDE, an external installer is available
>   on the Registered Users site: http://cc.embarcadero.com/myreg
>
> The BDE help remains in the XE7 help.

Comment: It's not like you weren't given ample warning that this was going to happen!  ;-)

Comment: Well, my Delphi journey started with Borland Delphi 7, and I but three years of self-taught knowledge, so unfortunately this is the first I hear of this change.

Comment: BDE was already  deprecated when Delhpi 7 was released, over 10 years ago!